# Having trouble generating card face value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to edit a beginner JS/css/html card game I made earlier.

When the user card is clicked on the webpage, the value of the two cards pulled are displayed. These values are then compared, and a winner is alerted. The score counter for the winner then increments by 1.

I'm ultimately trying to generate the correct face card based on the number value key and output it into the html.

**Just to clarify, I need the card faces for the Ace, King, Queen, and Jack**

```js
function randomizer(x) {
  var y = x * Math.random();
  var randnum = Math.round(y);
  return randnum;


}

function getcard(whosecard) {
  var suit = randomizer(3);
  var suitval;

  switch (suit) {
    case 0:
      suitval = "&spades;";
      document.getElementById(whosecard).style.color = "#000000";
      break;
    case 1:
      suitval = "&clubs;";
      document.getElementById(whosecard).style.color = "#000000";
      break;
    case 2:
      suitval = "&hearts;";
      document.getElementById(whosecard).style.color = "#e11b1b";
      break;
    case 3:
      suitval = "&diams;";
      document.getElementById(whosecard).style.color = "#e11b1b";
      break;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    document.getElementById(whosecard).innerHTML = suitval;
    var card = randomizer(13) + 1;
    while (card == 1) {
      card = randomizer(13) + 1;
    }
  }
  var fullcard;
  switch (card) {
    case 11:
      cardval = "&#9822; J";
      break;
    case 12:
      cardval = "&#9819; Q";
      break;
    case 13:
      cardval = "&#9818; K";
      break;
    case 14:
      cardval = "&#65;";
      break;
    default:
      cardval = card;
      break;
  }
  //document.getElementById(whoseval).innerHTML = cardval;
  fullcard = suitval + " " + card;

  document.getElementById(whosecard).innerHTML = fullcard;

  return fullcard;

}

function startgame() {
  document.getElementById("startbutton").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("yourcard").innerHTML = getcard("yourcard");
  document.getElementById("computercard").innerHTML = getcard("computercard");
  comparecard();
}

function comparecard() {
  var usercard = computercard = document.getElementById("yourcard").innerHTML;
  var computercard = document.getElementById("computercard").innerHTML;
  var winnermessage;
  var usernum = Number(usercard.substr(2));
  var computernum = Number(computercard.substr(2));



  if (usernum > computernum) {
    winnermessage = "You Win!";

  } else if (usernum < computernum) {
    winnermessage = "The Computer Wins!";


  } else {
    winnermessage = "It's a Tie!";



  }
  document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = winnermessage;
  calcscore(winnermessage);

}

function calcscore(winner) {
  var compscore = Number(document.getElementById("computerscore").innerHTML);
  var yourscore = Number(document.getElementById("yourscore").innerHTML);

  switch (winner) {
    case "You Win!":
      yourscore++;
      document.getElementById("yourscore").innerHTML = yourscore;
      break;
    case "The Computer Wins!":
      compscore++;
      document.getElementById("computerscore").innerHTML = compscore;
      break;
    default:
      yourscore++;
      compscore++;
      document.getElementById("yourscore").innerHTML = yourscore;
      document.getElementById("computerscore").innerHTML = compscore;
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.cardcontain,
.keycontain,
.headcontain,
.scorecontain {
  display: flex;
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

.cardcontain>div {
  height: 225px;
  width: 135px;
  font-size: 2em;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  /*width:22%;*/
}

.cardback {
  background-color: hsl(34, 53%, 82%);
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 5px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 5px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 10px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0) 10px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0) 35px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 35px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 40px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 40px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 50px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0) 50px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0) 60px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 60px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 70px, hsla(35, 91%, 65%, 0.5) 70px, hsla(35, 91%, 65%, 0.5) 80px, hsla(35, 91%, 65%, 0) 80px, hsla(35, 91%, 65%, 0) 90px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 90px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 110px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0) 110px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0) 120px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 120px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 140px), repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 5px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 5px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 10px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0) 10px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0) 35px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 35px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 40px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 40px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 50px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0) 50px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0) 60px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 60px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 70px, hsla(35, 91%, 65%, 0.5) 70px, hsla(35, 91%, 65%, 0.5) 80px, hsla(35, 91%, 65%, 0) 80px, hsla(35, 91%, 65%, 0) 90px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 90px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 110px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0) 110px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0) 140px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 140px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 160px);
}

.startmessage {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 5px 6px 2px #3c3b3b;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.keycontain>div {
  text-align: left;
  color: #888888;
  width: 50%;
}

.headcontain>div {
  text-align: center;
  color: #008800;
  width: 50%;
}

.scorecontain>p {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  color: #d0732d;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.cardgrid2 {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #651e1e;
}

.cardgrid3 {}

button {
  background-color: #57ac75;
}


/*
            .winner::before {
                display:block;
                content:" ";
                height:400px;
    
            }
            */

.winner {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #3f7a3b;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="headcontain">
  <div>
    <h2 class="cardgrid">Computer</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="cardgrid">You</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cardcontain">
  <div class="cardback"></div>
  <div id="computercard"></div>
  <div id="yourcard"></div>
  <div class="cardback startmessage" onclick="startgame()">
    <p id="startbutton">Click here to play!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="scorecontain">
  <p id="computerscore">0</p>
  <p id="yourscore">0</p>
</div>
<p class="winner" id="winner"></p>
<div class="keycontain">
  <div>
    <h3>Key: first digit</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>0 = Spade</li>
      <li>1 = Club</li>
      <li>2 = Heart</li>
      <li>3 = Diamond</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Key: second digit</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>11 = Jack</li>
      <li>12 = Queen</li>
      <li>13 = King</li>
      <li>14 = Ace</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tidied up your code a bit as half of it wasnt showing, but its not entirely clear what the question is here. Your code seems to already work exactly as you describe

Comment: Sorry I shouldve been more clear, I meant Jack, Queen, King, and Ace's face & values

Comment: Isnt that what the `switch` statement in `getcard` does? What _exactly_ is the issue? oooh wait I think I get it, you're still getting eg `12` insstead of `Q`

Comment: Exactly! I cant quite figure out how to get it working

Comment: You saw my answer, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic you're using for generating the value of the card is .... odd. Why would you need a `while` loop there? Just get rid of that

You actually have the right logic in your `switch` statement, where you set a variable called `cardval` but then you forget to use it

```
fullcard = suitval + " " + card; // should be cardval
```

Working snippet

```js
function randomizer(x) {
  var y = x * Math.random();
  var randnum = Math.round(y);
  return randnum;


}

function getcard(whosecard) {
  var suit = randomizer(3);
  var suitval;

  switch (suit) {
    case 0:
      suitval = "&spades;";
      document.getElementById(whosecard).style.color = "#000000";
      break;
    case 1:
      suitval = "&clubs;";
      document.getElementById(whosecard).style.color = "#000000";
      break;
    case 2:
      suitval = "&hearts;";
      document.getElementById(whosecard).style.color = "#e11b1b";
      break;
    case 3:
      suitval = "&diams;";
      document.getElementById(whosecard).style.color = "#e11b1b";
      break;
  }
  var card = randomizer(13)
  var fullcard;
  switch (card) {
    case 11:
      cardval = "&#9822; J";
      break;
    case 12:
      cardval = "&#9819; Q";
      break;
    case 13:
      cardval = "&#9818; K";
      break;
    case 14:
      cardval = "&#65;";
      break;
    default:
      cardval = card;
      break;
  }
  fullcard = suitval + " " + cardval;

  document.getElementById(whosecard).innerHTML = fullcard;

  return fullcard;

}

function startgame() {
  document.getElementById("startbutton").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("yourcard").innerHTML = getcard("yourcard");
  document.getElementById("computercard").innerHTML = getcard("computercard");
  comparecard();
}

function comparecard() {
  var usercard = computercard = document.getElementById("yourcard").innerHTML;
  var computercard = document.getElementById("computercard").innerHTML;
  var winnermessage;
  var usernum = Number(usercard.substr(2));
  var computernum = Number(computercard.substr(2));



  if (usernum > computernum) {
    winnermessage = "You Win!";

  } else if (usernum < computernum) {
    winnermessage = "The Computer Wins!";


  } else {
    winnermessage = "It's a Tie!";



  }
  document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = winnermessage;
  calcscore(winnermessage);

}

function calcscore(winner) {
  var compscore = Number(document.getElementById("computerscore").innerHTML);
  var yourscore = Number(document.getElementById("yourscore").innerHTML);

  switch (winner) {
    case "You Win!":
      yourscore++;
      document.getElementById("yourscore").innerHTML = yourscore;
      break;
    case "The Computer Wins!":
      compscore++;
      document.getElementById("computerscore").innerHTML = compscore;
      break;
    default:
      yourscore++;
      compscore++;
      document.getElementById("yourscore").innerHTML = yourscore;
      document.getElementById("computerscore").innerHTML = compscore;
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.cardcontain,
.keycontain,
.headcontain,
.scorecontain {
  display: flex;
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

.cardcontain>div {
  height: 225px;
  width: 135px;
  font-size: 2em;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  /*width:22%;*/
}

.cardback {
  background-color: hsl(34, 53%, 82%);
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 5px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 5px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 10px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0) 10px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0) 35px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 35px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 40px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 40px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 50px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0) 50px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0) 60px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 60px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 70px, hsla(35, 91%, 65%, 0.5) 70px, hsla(35, 91%, 65%, 0.5) 80px, hsla(35, 91%, 65%, 0) 80px, hsla(35, 91%, 65%, 0) 90px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 90px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 110px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0) 110px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0) 120px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 120px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 140px), repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 5px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 5px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 10px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0) 10px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0) 35px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 35px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 40px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 40px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 50px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0) 50px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0) 60px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 60px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 70px, hsla(35, 91%, 65%, 0.5) 70px, hsla(35, 91%, 65%, 0.5) 80px, hsla(35, 91%, 65%, 0) 80px, hsla(35, 91%, 65%, 0) 90px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 90px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0.5) 110px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0) 110px, hsla(5, 53%, 63%, 0) 140px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 140px, hsla(197, 62%, 11%, 0.5) 160px);
}

.startmessage {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 5px 6px 2px #3c3b3b;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.keycontain>div {
  text-align: left;
  color: #888888;
  width: 50%;
}

.headcontain>div {
  text-align: center;
  color: #008800;
  width: 50%;
}

.scorecontain>p {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  color: #d0732d;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.cardgrid2 {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #651e1e;
}

.cardgrid3 {}

button {
  background-color: #57ac75;
}


/*
            .winner::before {
                display:block;
                content:" ";
                height:400px;
    
            }
            */

.winner {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #3f7a3b;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="headcontain">
  <div>
    <h2 class="cardgrid">Computer</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2 class="cardgrid">You</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cardcontain">
  <div class="cardback"></div>
  <div id="computercard"></div>
  <div id="yourcard"></div>
  <div class="cardback startmessage" onclick="startgame()">
    <p id="startbutton">Click here to play!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="scorecontain">
  <p id="computerscore">0</p>
  <p id="yourscore">0</p>
</div>
<p class="winner" id="winner"></p>
<div class="keycontain">
  <div>
    <h3>Key: first digit</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>0 = Spade</li>
      <li>1 = Club</li>
      <li>2 = Heart</li>
      <li>3 = Diamond</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Key: second digit</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>11 = Jack</li>
      <li>12 = Queen</li>
      <li>13 = King</li>
      <li>14 = Ace</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```